# Playing from wav stream

Tags: c#, audio, ibm-cloud, naudio

```
            var result = service.Synthesize(

                text: text,
                accept: "audio/wav",

                voice: "en-US_AllisonVoice"
                //voice: "en-US_HenryV3Voice"

                );

            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"C:\Users\nkk01\Desktop\voice.wav"))

            {
                result.Result.WriteTo(fs);
                fs.Close();
                result.Result.Close();
            }

            var waveStream = new WaveFileReader(@"C:\Users\nkk01\Desktop\voice.wav");
            var waveOut = new WaveOutEvent();
            waveOut.Init(waveStream);

            Console.WriteLine("Playing");
            waveOut.Play();

            Console.WriteLine("Finished playing");
```

Hi this is my current code which is extremely inefficient as it has to save an audio stream to a file to play it. I would like to pass the audio stream directly to my laptop's speaker using the NAudio library. I still have not managed to find a solution. It will be of great help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with naudio but as far as i can see from their git hub repo, the constructor for WaveFileReader also accepts a stream instead of a filename ...

simply try writing everything you have to a memory stream instead of a file... don't forget to reposition the memory stream before you read it ('seek' to offset 0)